# Sending and using POST variables using jQuery.ajax()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, methods

Is it possible to access $_POST variables without appending all the form elements into the data attribute?

**Ajax call:**

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "ajax/user.php",
       data: {**data**},
       success: this.saveUserResponse
     });
```

**Accessing variables:**

```
if(isset($_POST['saveUser']) && $_POST['saveUser']){
  $user = $_POST['username'];
  ...
  ...  
  exit;
}
```

Or do i need to append all form elements to the data attribute, like:

```
var userId = $('#userId').val();
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "ajax/user.php",
       data: {user : userId, etc...  },
       success: this.saveUserResponse
     });
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `.serialize()` method on the form to do that for you.

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "ajax/user.php",
       data: $("#formid").serialize(),
       success: this.saveUserResponse
     });
```

See [Help with Jquery and multiple forms on a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997089/help-with-jquery-and-multiple-forms-on-a-page/).

You can also use the [jQuery Form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) to make this work a lot simpler. Using that, you can create a normal form in HTML (which you already have), set it up using `method="POST"` and `action="ajax/user.php"`, and then call `$("#formid").ajaxForm(this.saveUserResponse)` on load. This sets up everything and has the additional advantage that it will probably also work (in most rudimentary form) when JavaScript is disabled.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery will only send data that you explicitly pass to the server.

You can pass the values of all of the form elements by passing `$('form').serialize()`.